# How to force django ModelForm to use `verbose_name` from the model as a label?

Tags: django, django-forms

Code snippet:

[models.py]

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name=u"Tytuł")
```

[forms.py]

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}), required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = (
            'title',
        )
```

how to force label in form to use `verbose_name` and not `title`

I guess it is possible to link it in each field via `label=here_some_geeky_way_of_accessing_fields_meta_and_greping_verbose_name` but I think it should be possible somehow in more easy way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override the default widget for the field then you can use the `widgets` property of the form's meta:

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model =News
        fields = ('title', )
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
        }
```

In this case you don't need to re-define the form field. `ModelForm` will obtain the verbose name and the `required` flag from the model definition.

Comment: This is not work for me.